# What is the minimum number of piles to go from any permutation to any other permutation in a deck of $n$ cards.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say there is a machine that, given a deck of $n$ cards, can take one card from the top of the deck put it into one of any $h$ piles and repeat this until the deck is empty, at which point the machine can stack the pile in a specific order, resulting in a new deck.

What is the minimum $h$ for a given $n$ that will allow the machine to go from any permutation of $n$ cards to any **other** permutation of $n$ cards in a single pass through the machine.

There is the trivial solution where $h$ is equal to $n$ as the machine can put a single card in each pile and then stack them up in any order to achieve any desired permutation.

$h$ can not be 1 as that would only allow to reverse the order of the deck, so for $n=2$, $h$ must be 2. For $n=3$ it can be seen that $h$ can be 2 via working from all permutation to a single permutation, allowing for all permutation of 3 cards to be put back into the order $1, 2, 3$, except for the case where the input is $1, 2, 3$. The same can be said for $n=4$, where $h$ can be 3.

Past this I do not know where to go, especially for higher values of $n$ like for $n=52$ or $n=99$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do it with two piles.  On the first pass, put the desired top card in one pile and all the remaining cards in the other.  Put the top card on the bottom of the stack.  On the second pass  put the top and second cards in one pile and all the remaining cards in the other.  The top card will be on top of the second.  Pick up the top and second first, then the other cards.  Reverse the stack.  Put the first three cards in one stack and the rest in the other.  Continue.

Added:  If you need to do it in one pass you need $n$ piles and the order that enforces that is to have the deck in perfect order.  The first card is $1$ and it goes in a pile.  You can't put any more cards in that pile.  The next card is $2$ and it goes in some other pile.  Again you can't put any more cards in that pile and so on.  Each pile needs to consist of a run of cards that were in reverse order but perhaps with other cards intervening in the original deck.

Comment: If you're after a more efficient algorithm, you can give each card a number according to the spot you want it to end up in, express that in binary, and work one bit position at a time (least significant first), putting all the 1s in one pile and all the 0s in the other. At least I think that _should_ work, I haven't looked through all the details.

Comment: @Arthur:  I believe there are more efficient ones, I just wanted one that was easy to understand to show $2$ piles work.

Comment: @RossMillikan, Thanks for this answer. But I was thinking minimum number of piles in one pass, sorry for not making that clear, though I do wonder how different number of passes makes $n$ and $h$ vary.